# How can this definition be improved?

Tags: first-order-logic, article-writing

On my new theorem I have to introduce some new notions that may be extrange in academics reading and in order to get it accepted by the reader I would like to be as clear and correct as possible. Please let me know how can I improve this definition, as well as it needs a proof or an example or an extended explanation.

*The **m-Crown** of a set S, denoted by $S^m$*, is the family of sets of every subset of its index set of cardinality $m$ no containing its index, such that

$\forall(X_i \in S^m : i \in S) \rightarrow X_i = \{ x \subset S :(i\notin x 
\land|x|=m) \} $

Comment: As I have said before: That is not a well-formed sentence in any syntax I have seen.

Comment: Try explaining in plain language what it is you are trying to formalize. Or in what context this came up.

Comment: In spite of your efforts it is still totally unclear to me what the m-Crown of a set is.

Comment: So it looks like for a given cardinal $m$ and $i\in S$ he has $X_i=\{A\subseteq S\ |\ i\not\in A\text{ and }|A|=m\}$ and then $S^m=\{X_i\}_{i\in S}$.

Comment: @freakish Yes, I think that's the most reasonable interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you want to start from simpler objects before constructing more complex. Something like this:

> Let $m$ be a cardinal number and $S$ a set. For $i\in S$ define
>   $$T(S, i, m)=\big\{A\subseteq S\ \big|\ i\not\in A\text{ and }|A|=m\big\}$$
>   The family $\big\{T(S, i, m)\big\}_{i\in S}$ will be called **the m-Crown** of a set $S$ and we will denote it by $S^m$.

(I'm not a native english speaker, but this sounds quite ok to me)

I deliberately used $T(S,i,m)$ instead of vague $X$ to emphasize the connection between this set, $S$, cardinal $m$ and index $i$.

I also encourage you to not use formal, mathematical, symbolic sentences like the one you've used at the end. Unless absolutely necessary. It is hard to read and understand it.

**// Edit:** As suggested by @DanielWainfleet $S^m$ is already used in some other context. In order to avoid ambiguity it is a good idea to replace the symbol with something else, like for example $\text{Cr}(S,m)$.

Comment: My edit was for a trivial mis-spelling.... I would advise against calling it $S^m$ because that is already standard notation for something else.

Comment: Thanks freakish ... you are a genious !! the only one !!!

Comment: Although I agree with the fact that the notation $S^m$ may be confusing as is already standar of "degree" notation, but it is correct since items on the family are all sets of the same cardinality $m$ and it represents an abstract notation of degree.